# jQuery: Reset all other div's properties except currently clicked div

Tags: jquery, css, html, toggle

I'm trying to make it so that **when I click a div all other divs become 'deselected'** (i.e. only selected div's `background-image` is different, others get reset to original), and so that only the clicked is selected/active. Each div has a separate on/off image.

http://jsfiddle.net/sergep/5QsCy/

The code has a lot of repetition. I am not really sure how to approach the idea of 'deselecting' all other divs (except for the active one) without having to use a lot more redundant code.

Is there anyway to tidy up (i.e. generalize and remove redundancy) my jsFiddle:

```
$(".gameboy").click(function () {
   var img1 = "url(\"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/funky/136/Game-1-128.png\")";
   var img2 = "url(\"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/funky/136/Game-2-128.png\")";
    if ($(this).css("background-image") == img1) {
        $(this).css("background-image", img2);
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-image", img1);
    }
});
$(".switch").click(function () {
   var img1 = "url(\"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mobiactions/512/turn_off_on_power-128.png\")";
   var img2 = "url(\"http://icdn.pro/images/en/o/n/on-off-icone-4799-128.png\")";
    if ($(this).css("background-image") == img1) {
        $(this).css("background-image", img2);
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-image", img1);
    }
});
$(".face").click(function () {
   var img1 = "url(\"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glyph/227/Smile-128.png\")";
   var img2 = "url(\"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glyph/227/Pacman-1-128.png\")";
    if ($(this).css("background-image") == img1) {
        $(this).css("background-image", img2);
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background-image", img1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use classes in your CSS and add/remove those classes using JS, rather than programmatically changing each background-image. It will make your code a LOT more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since all you're changing is the style, why not create a class 'active' and apply it to the div that was just clicked, while at the same time removing that class from its sibling divs. Can all be summed up in one simple click function:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('div').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

then just style your css for the .active class of each div:

```
.gameboy.active {...}
.switch.active {...}
.face.active {...}
```

By the way, the 'div' selector in the click function is just for the example. Most likely you won't want every div on your site to be clickable, therefore I'd either give a class to all 3 of these divs, or specify them using a more specific css selector